# Why can't I pass string.begin() right away for the function with (string::Iterator& it) argument?

Tags: c++, reference, iterator, arguments

I tried to pass `str.begin()` iterator for calling a function with `(string::Iterator& it)` argument.
When I tried `func(str.begin())`, it didn't work.
On the other hand, when I tried pre-declaration for the iterator, it worked pretty well.
It goes like

```
string::iterator it = str.begin();
func(it);
```

In my opinion, I see no difference between those ways. Can anybody tell me why the first one didn't work?

Comment: Do you understand why `void f(int&); f(42);` won't work, but `int i = 42; foo(i);` works?

Comment: please include the compiler error message in the question. Maybe you don't see the difference but there is one and the message should already tell a lot

Comment: Hi, Jarod42. Maybe i has it's memory space for referencing but 42 doesn't?

Comment: Jarod42, is it like there's no point of using reference argument for the function if I don't pass a declared variable and retain the changes in the function outside?